# When new answer is loaded on the page, accepted mark is not refreshed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, live-refresh

Steps to reproduce:

1. Ask a question
2. Get and accept an answer
3. Get one more answer and accept it in some other browser tab
4. Return to the first tab and click panel for loading a new answer
5. Both answers are shown as accepted

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Using the same question page from multiple browser tabs has a multitude of inconsistencies, the live update feature was never designed to cover those cases.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I expect it not to refresh if the other user is looking too.

Comment: Please reproduce **that** then and report that as a bug. But take into account that there are optimisations in place to ignore refreshing stuff you yourself just did.

Comment: In other words, just because it doesn't work *when you interact with the same page in two different tabs*, doesn't mean that other users in other browsers will see the same.

Comment: Btw, you want take a look at a [page-screenshot-tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/fireshot/)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt, I used [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) to take a screenshot of scrollable window.